# Extraer Columnas de un txt y guardarlas en arreglos

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Me gustaria saber como sacar los valores de varias columnas de un archivo de txt y pasar cada columna a un arreglo, en este caso serian con 3 columnas por lo tanto serian 3 arreglos

Estoy usando python con Spyder y soy nuevo en Pyton.

Gracias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002046/python-turning-text-column-into-array-where-i-can-access-each-number-in-the-a Encontre este enlace que dice como.